# Incorrect syntax in table variable insert via select

Tags: t-sql

I can't figure out what in the world this is complaining about, looks fine to me:

```
DECLARE @newidentity int 
SET @newidentity = scope_identity()
select @newidentity

Insert into @Companies (select @newidentity, Name from Company where Name = 'Parker')
```

I get the following for the insert line:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without brackets and specify fields of companies, please:

```
INSERT INTO @Companies 
            (field1, 
             field2) 
SELECT @newidentity, 
       Name 
FROM   Company 
WHERE  Name = 'Parker'
```

What `@Companies` is?

Comment: hmm so with table variables you can't use the shortcut of leaving out the field definitions before you specify the fields to be selected for insert?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - Yes you can. It is the brackets around the `select` that were the problem.